# Why can't we use binary search in jump search instead of linear search?

Tags: algorithm, search

The following article explains Jump Search:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jump-search/

The last step is a linear search.
Why can't we use binary search if the array is already sorted and time complexity of binary search is log(n) while of the linear search it is n?

Answer (score 5):

The use case for jump search (O(√n)) over binary search (O(log n)) is when jumping back is expensive. Replacing the linear search in jump search would be counterproductive in that regard.

Comment: Can you elaborate any scenario where jumping back is more expensive? Does "jumping back is expensive" refer to more cache misses?

Comment: @Shubham we might be reading from a spinning medium, where scanning forward is cheap and randomly seeking is expensive.